# ActiveSupport can't load Sass engine under Rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, require, activesupport

I'm trying to use Sass engine in a controller like in this [blog post](http://nubyonrails.com/articles/dynamic-css). But Rails (2.3.4) ActiveSupport can't load it because of an error:

```
ArgumentError (Anonymous modules have no name to be referenced by):
  haml (3.0.25) lib/sass/script/color.rb:19
  haml (3.0.25) lib/sass/script/literal.rb:10
  haml (3.0.25) lib/sass/script/string.rb:1
  haml (3.0.25) lib/sass/script/operation.rb:2
  haml (3.0.25) lib/sass/script.rb:5
  haml (3.0.25) lib/sass/engine.rb:22
  app/controllers/stylesheets_controller.rb:1
```

Here's the code in `Sass::Script::Color`

```
class << self; include Haml::Util; end
```

I've tried with the latest Haml version and also version 2.2.24 with the same result. Is there a compatible version? Is there a problem on my side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was quite stupid, the `Sass::Script::Color` file wasn't requiring `Haml::Util`, so I had to do it myself:

```
require 'haml/util'
require 'sass/engine'
```